# What does the statement const {tz, msg} = this.state; mean in the below code?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, expo, react-native-fetch-blob

The use of this seems always confusing to me. As in the below source code.
Can anyone explain what does the statement const {tz, msg} = this.state; mean in the below code?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentTime: null, msg: 'now', tz: 'PST'
    }
  }

  getApiUrl() {
    **const {tz, msg} = this.state;**
    const host = 'https://andthetimeis.com';
    return host + '/' + tz + '/' + msg + '.json';
  }

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const {tz, msg} = this.state;` is equivalent to

```
const tz = this.state.tz;
const msg = this.state.msg;
```

It is called [ES6 Destructuring Assignment](http://es6-features.org/#ObjectMatchingShorthandNotation). Basically it will reduce lines of code. It will be good if you can look into other [ES6 features](http://es6-features.org).

Comment: That seemed quite convicing although I have another doubt.

Comment: In an earlier class just above this example they have defined tz, and msg in an another way.






```
export class TimeForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.fetchCurrentTime = this.fetchCurrentTime.bind(this);
    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    const {tz, msg} = this.props;
    this.state = {tz, msg};
  }
```

Comment: It is same. ES6 Destructuring Assignment.

Comment: That helped. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is called `Object Destructuring` in Javascript. You can use it with Object and Arrays.

Like.

```
For Array

const [a, b] = [10, 20];

For Object

let options = {
  title: "Menu",
  width: 100,
  height: 200
};

let {title, width, height} = options;
```

You can read further here https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment.

So in your case it's

```
const {tz, msg} = this.state
```

is similar to accessing it as

```
const tz = this.state.tz
const msg = this.state.msg
```

Comment: Oh Ok. But, why would anyone reassign values to the already defined title, width and height?

Comment: We are not reassigning it. These are the properties on the object, we are accessing it directly using destructuring.

Imagine you have an HTTP response object and you want to retrieve ``name`` from it. You will simply use ``const {name} = response``.

Answer (score 1):

That's called `Object destructuring`. This is es6 method.

The **destructuring assignment syntax** is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

## OLD METHOD

```
var obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3};

var a = obj.a;
var b = obj.b;
var c = obj.c;

console.log("value of a is "+ a);
console.log("value of b is "+ b);
console.log("value of c is "+ b);
```

## Destructuring

```
const obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3};

const { a, b, c } = obj;

console.log("value of a is "+ a);
console.log("value of b is "+ b);
console.log("value of c is "+ b);
```

you can get more info about **destructuring** here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 0):

It means you have state which has two key value pair like `tz` and `msg`

so whenever type like this you get value from that directly then were you print value from there like `tz` and `msg`.